# Shopware - Not able to show my page in My apps

Tags: shopware6

I created Shopware App. I wanted to show my app in Iframe. But always showing "Whoops! You’ve moved too fast and lost orientation."

This is my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shopware/platform/trunk/src/Core/Framework/App/Manifest/Schema/manifest-1.0.xsd">
    <meta>
        <name>TF</name>
        <label>TF</label>
        <label lang="de-DE">TF</label>
        <author>TF</author>
        <copyright></copyright>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <license>MIT</license>
    </meta>
    <setup>
        <secret>test</secret>
        <registrationUrl>https://example.com/shopware/register</registrationUrl>
    </setup>
    <permissions>
        <read>order</read>
        <read>product</read>
    </permissions>
    <admin>
        <main-module source="https://example.com/app/shopware"/>
    </admin>
</manifest>
```

I am using Laravel for my site. And I created route like

```
Route::get('/app/shopware', 'ShopwareController@showApp');
```

and my function is

```
public function showApp(Request $request)
{
   echo 'Showing TF';
}
```

If I access this URL directly its working fine, but in Shopware showing error like this

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to append the shop id and a timestamp to the URL in the `registrationUrl` tags. This could be the reason shopware throws this error.

Take a look in here: [Add custom module](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/administration/add-custom-modules.html#leave-loading-state). There is an example of how a request should look like.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add script code in the response html

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        window.parent.postMessage('sw-app-loaded', '*');
    }
</script>
```